# Material UI - React JS : Change selection mode DataGrid with switch button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am trying to make a datagrid with a switch button to switch from simple to multiple selection.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const { selectedTransaction } = useSelector(...) 
const [enableMultipleSelection, setEnableMultipleSelection] = useState<boolean | undefined>(true);

const handleEnableMultipleSelectionChange = useCallback((_: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, checked: boolean) => {
    dispatch(toggleSelect([]))
// testing with setTimeOut
// work only 1 time 
    setTimeOut(() => { setEnableMultipleSelection(checked) }, 1000)

  }, [dispatch]);

const handleSelectionChange = useCallback((value: GridSelectionModel) => {
    dispatch(toggleSelect(value))
  }, [dispatch]);



<FormControlLabel control={<Switch checked={enableMultipleSelection} onChange={handleEnableMultipleSelectionChange} />} label="Select" />

<DataGrid
            disableSelectionOnClick={enableMultipleSelection}
            selectionModel={selectedTransaction}
            onSelectionModelChange={handleSelectionChange}
            checkboxSelection={enableMultipleSelection}
            {...}
/>
```

I don't know if it possible with Mui component because when i do that i have some error with it.

```
index-esm.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueFormatter')
    at Object.getCellParams (index-esm.js:15)
    at ai.t.current.hasOwnProperty.t.current.<computed> [as getCellParams] (index-esm.js:1)
    at Object.setCellFocus (index-esm.js:15)
    at ai.t.current.hasOwnProperty.t.current.<computed> [as setCellFocus] (index-esm.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index-esm.js:15)
```

Really need Help please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onSelectionModelChange` to only keep the last marked checkbox:

```
onSelectionModelChange={(selection) => {
      if (!enableMultipleSelection && selection.length > 1) {
        const selectionSet = new Set(selectionModel);
        const result = selection.filter((s) => !selectionSet.has(s));
        setSelectionModel(result);
      } else {
        setSelectionModel(selection);
      }
    }}
```

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datagrid-with-multiple-or-single-selection-64usm?file=/src/datagrid.js:2384-2745) for the example.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But i really need switch the selection mode with the `checkboxSelection` props.
But i think it's impossible